# Getting CST and EST time same in java

Tags: java

I am getting same time for EST and CST.Please find the code below.

`Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));` and 
`Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CST"));` both returns the same time.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Remember, a "java.util.Date" value represents the *SAME INSTANT* for any time zone in the world.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you get the same time is because EST returns Standard time while CST the Daylight time.

> ```
> Date today = new Date();
> DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:SS z");
> df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Eastern"));
> String time = df.format(today);
> System.out.println(time);
> df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
> time = df.format(today);
> System.out.println(time);
> df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CST"));
> time = df.format(today);
> System.out.println(time);
> ```

and this is the output:

> ```
> 04:55:839 EDT
> 03:55:839 EST
> 03:55:839 CDT
> ```

EST time is not the correct time because it is actually 04:55 there right now, so `US/Eastern` will give you the correct (EDT) time. As a rule of thumb, I would recommend always using the `US/Eastern` and `US/Central` formats for safety.

Comment: Is there anyway to get "US/Eastern or US/Central" from EST or CST respectively in Java?

Comment: what you need are the Daylight times (US/Eastern and US/Central), not the Standard ones, because they keep track of the daylight saving time (clock switching in March and November). EST - as you can see is not reliable.